# Modelling different usertypes in a relational database

Tags: database, inheritance, modeling

First of all, I'm sorry about the feedback-nature of this question. I'm trying to generalize it as much as I can so others can gain from it as well, but I don't really have anyone to give me feedback on this design, so I hoped you guys could help me.

With that being said, I wan't to model different usertypes in my database. I would like to have the credentials for the usertypes to be shared though. This problem is basically about inheritance, which is something that the RDB's doesn't do too well.

I did however come up with this design:
[DB design http://img48.imageshack.us/img48/9196/dbdesign.png](http://img48.imageshack.us/img48/9196/dbdesign.png)

.. but I'm unsure if I should be satisfied with it. What I don't like about it is the amount of business-contracts in it. First of all, I don't know which usertype belongs to a given credential, which means that I potentially have to search N tables, with N being the number of usertypes I got. Therefore, I thought of linking the type of a user with the roles he or she is in. So, if a user with credentials A has the roles of "UserType1" and "UserType2" I would expect to have a tuggle in the UserType1 and UserType2 tables representing him or her. - and I'm not sure if I like these "business-logic"-constraints.. :)

Any feedback on this given design would be very much appreciated, just as any alternative designs would be.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a discriminator column in the parent if it's analogous to an abstract class in OO. The discriminator has a different value for each child type. If you're clever, it's an fk to a table with one row per child type.

Or you can just rely on that the join of authcredentials to usertype1 succeeds for any usertype1, but for no other child type, and similarly for the other tables. On a left outer join to each child table, all columns (but particularly the id) of the type it isn't are null, and the id it is isn't null. You can then add a calculated column based on this:

```
select 
 a.*, b.*, c.*, 
 case when b.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as is_usertype1, 
 case when c.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as is_usertype2,
from authcredentials a 
 left outer join usertype1 b on (a.id = b.authcredential_id )
 left outer join usertype2 c on (a.id = c.authcredential_id );
```

Then make that select a view for ease of use. Inserts will still be to the separate table usertype and usertype2, but then in OO programming, ctors aren't inherited either and two subclasses of a common based don't necessarily have similar ctors.

Just as in C++, where the base class is constructed before the derived class, you'll have to create the parent row bfore you can create a child row (you need the FK).

postgresql explicitly supports table inheritance just like this. Hibernate ORM supports it for mapping tables to Java subclasses.